# passing array in header (php) and passing it again to javascript using onload event

Tags: javascript, php

what is the right way to pass the php array to header then post it in another file then pass it using onload event to a javascript file here is my code and it is not working

the code for the first php file

```
header("location: Rules.php?varFields=".http_build_query($varFields));
```

the code for the second php file where the php array is passed

```
$ddd = $_GET['varFields'];

<body onload="cmbRuleField(<?php echo $ddd;?>);" >
```

the code for the external javascript file

```
var varDisplay = JSON.stringify(arrayyy);
```

and also tried this one

```
var varDisplay = JSON.parse(arrayyy);
```

Answer (score 0):

`http_build_query` generates a query string, whereas what you want is a JSON encoded string. Instead of `http_build_query` use `json_encode`:

```
header( 'Location: Rules.php?varFields=' . json_encode( $varFields ) );
```

Documentation: http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: do i have to  do  thi in this part? $ddd = json_decode($_GET['varFields']);

Comment: @user3287181 I don't know. This is your code. Do you have to do the first redirect at all? An `echo $_GET['varFields'];` would be fine too, to pass a JSON encoded string to the final output.

Comment: yup sir it is necessary cause im going to pass several php query  as array variable to the javascript function for speed purposes, so like what you just said it would be like this? $ddd = json_encode($_GET['varFields']); and how about in the javascript function will it be like this? var varDisplay = JSON.stringify(arrayyy);

Comment: @user3287181 No, do not encode the data twice. You have to encode it before appending it to the URL in the redirect script. Do not use `$ddd = json_encode($_GET['varFields']);` – this would encode the JSON encoded data as JSON string. Just print it as it is. You don't even need to use `JSON.parse` in the JS, since you already passing a JSON object…

Comment: so i just need to pass it like this? <body onload="cmbRuleField(<?php echo $_GET['varFields']; ?>);" >